# Override NHibernate Property Type runtime

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

It's possible to override a property Type of a mapping (hbm.xml file, NOT fluent) on NHibernate?

Context:
I'm working on application that connects basically on SQL Server  (LEGACY DATABASE SCHEMA), but it must work on some Oracle databases too. We've a lot of entities and we've discard to keep two versions of the mapping files, so we decide to define a base mapping (SQL Server) and do some guided modifications in order to work on Oracle (like id generator, column and table names, ...).

Now we've got a new problem with the LONG Oracle fields (LEGACY OBSOLETE FIELD TYPE), it didn't work on NHibernate and we must define a Custom IUserType (http://sonyarouje.com/2012/11/07/nhibernate-and-oracle-long-varchar-field/), this solution is compatible with SQLServer but it requires the DLL Oracle.DataAccess.dll, and in order to avoid this problematic dll we would set this custom type on runtime only when we're connecting on Oracle. But the member Type of Property (NHibernate) is readonly and I haven't found any way to set it.

I'm using NHibernate 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

We should distinguish `ISessionFactory` and NHibernate configuration.

In general, we can create as **many configurations** in runtime, as we want. How to do dynamically is briefly shown here:

[3.1. Programmatic Configuration](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-programmatic)

But once we use the configuration to recieve `ISessionFactory` - it can not be changed:

> An instance of NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration represents an entire set of mappings of an application's .NET types to a SQL database. **The Configuration is used to build an (immutable) ISessionFactory.** The mappings are compiled from various XML mapping files.

So, I would say, we can in this case create **more Factories**, from more configurations (which could be pretty dynamically created). And that could solve the issue, based on environment... From some condition/configuration  we will know which NHibernate configuration to use... and that will give us appropriate Factory.

Comment: Thanks Radim, but despite of the "immutability" of the Configuration I've changed some db parameters (id generator, tables and column names, ...) and I thought It could be possible to change the property type in the same way. But I would intercept the configuration to dinamically assign the Type of the Property when I'm in Oracle, I don't want to copy&paste the mapping file, because I've a lot of entities (ca. 200) and I can't mantain 2 versions of all entities.

Comment: Marc, I would suggest... do not do that. It is not the way, not the way which could be maintained... it will bring you only problems. Just use configuration, conditional one, to create special Factories for special purposes. Anything inside of the Session Factory is NOT for external adjustment. That's the OOP... and encapsulation. What if new version interanally change something? So. If I can give you advice - create special, dynamic configuration - DO not change the Factory once created. Hope it helps a bit...

Comment: [My last comment was sent before I finish it] The last question is: could I intercept the configuration to dinamically assign the Type of the Property when I'm in Oracle, I don't want to copy&paste the mapping file, because I've a lot of entities (ca. 200) and I can't mantain 2 versions of all entities. I want to work with a base, and "specific and centralized" modifications over it.

Comment: That sounds reasonable... exactly what I say. Seems we are on the same wave! ;) So, there are many methods and one of them should be **`configuration.AddDocument(XmlDocument)`** so we can find the "xml-hbm" file, change the type (xml operations) and pass adjusted result to `Configuration` object. That could be exactly the way for you... Just play with, I'd say. The `Configuration` object is really very dynamic ..

Comment: Sounds good, but requires a change of the current common (sql-oracle) configuration strategy and it's hard hand work. I'll wait for another hacky-tricky solution (or a miracle) some days before works on your wave! ;)